# what is the maximum number of perpendicular bisectors of diameters of a convex polygon?

Tags: geometry

we have a convex polygon with n vertices. what is the maximum number   ( over all n vertices polygons)  of the perpendicular bisectors of all the n.(n-1)/2  "edges" ( we call a segment joining any two vertices an "edge") which are themselves edges?
( in other word , each time an edge be a perpendicular bisector of another edge we count one)

( My rough guess is n.(n-1)/4)...

Comment: trying regular polygon i get n.(n-2)/4

Comment: Regarding terminology, a line segment joining two vertices is often called a “chord”

Comment: yes Dap , thanks, you are right ,so i am looking for number of chords  which are also perpendicular bisectors of  other chords.